# Top reason not to use EJB 3.0 again?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0

The scenario

- You have developed a webapp using EJBs version 3.
- The system is deployed, delivered and is used by the customer.

If you would have to rewrite the system from scratch, would you use EJBs again?

**Yes**: Don't answer this question, answer [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105544/most-important-problem-solved-by-ejb-3) instead.

**No**: Provide the top reason for not using EJBs again, based on your personal experience.

Let the answer contain just **one** reason. This will let other readers vote up the number one reason to stay away from EJB 3.

Answer (score 2):

The project did not have any of the problems that EJBs are supposed to solve. Using EJBs just made it harder to code, to debug, to build, to deploy and to document and understand.

Answer (score 1):

The top reason for not using EJB 3.0 again? Maybe you can wait for EJB 3.1 which does away with a major piece of insanity: the mandatory local interface.

https://blogs.oracle.com/kensaks/entry/optional_local_business_interfaces

Comment: There is no mandatory local interface for POJOs. Give them a try?

Answer (score 0):

Having to do relationship-child management yourself: Hibernate's all-delete-orphan didn't make it into the 3.0 spec.

Answer (score 0):

Coding an app in EJB is too bulky and in my experience you can get away with a light weight alternative

Comment: I think this is not true anymore with ejb3.